# If Post Type equals, then display X content

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-content

I just need to say in single.php if post type = x then display y. Else, don't display it.

Answer (score 15):

```
if( get_post_type() == 'post_type_slug' ) {
    //do some stuff
} else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Should do it, alternately you can use templates to handle that, which wordpress has setup pretty well by default. See the [codex page on template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), specifically I find the [visual overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) to be quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for? (where 'product' would be the post type)

```
if ( is_singular('product') ) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what exactly `y` is, but this should probably help you out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type